# Usage of @TestCaseName with @FileParameters in JUnitParams

Tags: junit4, junitparams

I use JUnit4 with JUnitParams for testing and I want to know more about the usage of the `@TestCaseName` annotation. I understand the usage of `@TestCaseName` with the `@Parameters` annotation, but I want to know about how to use `@TestCaseName` with the `@FileParmeters` annotation.

Answer (score 0):

`@TestCaseName` allows you to modify how the name of the test case is presented in reports (eg. in your IDE or in the Maven Surefire report). The default naming is `{method}({params}) [{index}]`. You can use placeholders to create your own test case names. See Javadoc of `junitparams.naming.TestCaseName#value`:

> A template of the individual test case name. This template can contain
>   macros, which will be substituted by their actual values at runtime.
>
> Supported macros are:
>
> - **{index}** - index of
>     parameters set (starts from zero). Hint: use it to avoid names
>     duplication.
> - **{params}** - parameters set joined by
>     comma.
> - **{method}** - testing method name.
> - **{0}**, **{1}**, **{2}** - single parameter by index in current parameters set.
>         If there is no parameter with such index, it will use empty string.
>
> Lets assume, that we are testing Fibonacci
>   sequence generator. We have a test with the following signature
>
> ```
> @Parameters({ "0,1", "8,34" })
> public void testFibonacci(int indexInSequence, int expectedNumber) { ... }
> ```
>
> Here are some examples, that can be used as a test name template:
>
> - `{method}({params})` => testFibonacci(0, 1), testFibonacci(8, 34)
> - `fibonacci({0}) = {1}` => fibonacci(0) = 1, fibonacci(8) = 34
> - `{0} element should be {1}` => 0 element should be 1, 8 element should be 34
> - `Fibonacci sequence test #{index}` => Fibonacci sequence test #0, Fibonacci sequence test #1

`@FileParameters` does not have any relation to `@TestCaseName` - it's simply a way to provide parameters to a test method from a file. Using the example above, instead of `@Parameters` you could use `@FileParameters("/path/to/file.txt")` and have a `/path/to/file.txt` with content

```
0,1
8,34
```

to achieve the same results.